# Binding nested ItemsControls to nested collections

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am trying to show pages in my WPF/Caliburn Micro application. The pages should be presented in a rectangular way to the user. My idea is to use a collection (the rows) of collections (the columns) of my base view model for the pages:

```cs
public BindableCollection<BindableCollection<BaseViewModel>> Children { get; set; }
```

And do something like this in the associated View:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Children">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding /}">
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And this is wrong - I don't get what to put into the inner ItemsControl.

Thanks for any idea!

## Solution

I am still not sure whether this is the perfect solution, but it works and seems not too hacky to me:

```
            <ItemsControl x:Name="Children">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forward slash in a `Binding.Path` means the current item from the parent collection, but that won't as an `ItemsSource` value because it's not a collection:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding /}">   <!-- This won't work  here -->
```

You also need to define your inner `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. Try something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> <!-- Bind to the whole data item (a collection) here -->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate> <!-- Display your BaseViewModel data items here -->
                        <YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you! While this did not provide the immediate solution for my problem (I think it was related to Caliburn Micro specifics), it gave me the right idea to solve it. I'll update the question accordingly.