# Data binding in UWP to nested collection

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to dig into a nested observable collection in UWP, which consists another observable collection inside it, and then bind it to my XAML.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A code example of your observable collections would help but you could do something like this...

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectCollection { get; set;}
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string ObjectName {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<AnotherObject> AnotherObjectCollection { get; set; }
}
```

And in your XAML you can bind to these collection similar to this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView1" Grid.Column="0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <Datatemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectName}"/>
            </Datatemplate
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Grid Grid.Column=1 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListView1, Path=SelectedItem}"> 
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherObjectCollection}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In this example, the DataContext of the second Grid is bound to the selected item in ListView1.

Comment: 'DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListView1, Path=SelectedItem}"' What if the user does not select an item in  the ListView but the data should still show up?

Comment: This is a good point. The question didn't give too much specificity, so I assumed that the user would select an item in the one list and it would drill down in the second list. An option in your case would be to set the SelectedIndex = 0; in the Code Behind OnNavigatedTo method to set the context to the first item in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Allen Rufolo's Solution works. But Here is another way of approaching this.

[x:Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) is newly implemented and available for UWP. My Answer is based on x:Bind

**Sample Classes**

```
public class MainItems
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubItems> SubItemsList { get; set; }
}

public class SubItems
{
    public string SubItemName { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
ObservableCollection<MainItems> _data = new ObservableCollection<MainItems>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    MainItems _mainItems = new MainItems();
    _mainItems.ItemName = "Main" + i.ToString();
    _mainItems.SubItemsList = new ObservableCollection<SubItems>();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        SubItems _subItems = new SubItems()
        {
            SubItemName = "SubItem" + i.ToString()
        };
        _mainItems.SubItemsList.Add(_subItems);
    }
    _data.Add(_mainItems);
}
```

**My XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyMainList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MainItems">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemName}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubItemsList}" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SubItems">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind SubItemName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**x:Bind** gives you an easy way to Bind your Nested Observable Collection

**Output**

[image]

Comment: can we remove the space (from left) between those main item and subitem? means subitem should vertically come under main item.

Comment: @nsds by default `ListViewItem` has default 12px Margin on the left. So if you want to remove it, you can either retemplate the `ListViewItem` or add Margin="-12,0,0,0" on the second `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I get what do you need, but I guess that it could be the same as for WPF.

Check out questions and answers for the next questions:

- [Binding nested ItemsControls to nested collections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556568/182344)
- [Nested ObservableCollection data binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984156/nested-observablecollection-data-binding-in-wpf)
- [WPF Binding on Nested ItemControls with Sub Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127102/wpf-binding-on-nested-itemcontrols-with-sub-collection)
- [Databinding for nested collections in XAML (WPF and Silverlight)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/harryh/2010/06/12/databinding-for-nested-collections-in-xaml-wpf-and-silverlight/)